# Windows Scheduler & C#

Tags: c#, windows-task-scheduler

I have a script I wrote in C# (part of a ASP.NET application) that would reset a number if the end date of a booking is reached. I would like to automate the process, so each time an end date of booking is reached, it will send an email notifying that period is expired and also execute my script to reset the counter.

I heard that Windows Scheduler could be used? I know cron is perfect for this job, but unfortunately it is windows of course I am using. Any hints on what to do for automation of tasks above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Go to:

> ```
> Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler
> ```

Create a new task and specify date, time, frequency, etc.

Your C# program can be invoked from the task you created on the step above.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I either write a small C# console application or use [C# Script](http://www.csscript.net/) for this. If I would understand the "strange" (IMHO) syntax of [Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), this would be the preferable way to do.

No matter what you use, you usually *cannot* use C# code that is included inside an ASP.NET application. Instead, extract the code into one of the possibilities above and use the Task Scheduler to create a task with the following options:

- Depending on your requirements, the scheduled task should be created to run with an administrative user.
- Depending on your requirements, the scheduled task should have the “Run with highest privileges” checkbox set.

You could schedule the task to e.g. run every *n* minutes/hours, even if no user is logged in.

Comment: Hmmm I really have no idea where to go from here...so if i write a console application, like any guidelines on that?